# Show only one element of a panel using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and I am trying to figure out how it's different modules work. So, I am working on a project on which I wanna achieve an accordion-like style for a page, in which a table is shown when I click a panel button. The HTML code that creates(dynamically from a database) the div elements I modify is posted below.The problem is that in this panel, any number of tables can be shown,while I need to only have one opened at a time,so when one opens,the one opened before it should close.Any ideas how I can achieve this functionality?(I assume the error is because the showDB variable is local to each table scope, but I don't know how to work around it.) Thanks!'   `

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.services">
    <div ng-show="showSection(key)" class="top_panel-section">
        <button class="btn top_btn btn-header" type="button" name="showDB"
            ng-click="showDB=!showDB">{{key}}</button>

        <table ng-show="showDB"
            class="n-table toptable table-responsive  n-table-standard n-table-striped n-table-hover">
            <thead class="n-table-thead">
                <tr>
                    <th width="70%">VM Name</th>
                    <th width="30%">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="n-table-body">
                <tr ng-repeat="vm in value.vms">
                    <td width="76%">{{vm.vm}}</td>
                    <td width="24%" ng-style="getStatusStyle(vm.status)">
                        {{vm.status}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should remove that local `showDB` variable to achieve what you need.

You can easily replace it with a `$scope.activeKey` and evaluating it by the

`<button ... name="showDB" ng-click="activateKey(key)">{{key}}</button>`

And in your controller:

```
$scope.activeKey = null;
$scope.activateKey = function (keyToBeActivated) {
   $scope.activeKey = keyToBeActivated;
}
```

Now you can reach that exclusivity by checking:

`<table ng-show="activeKey === key" ... >`

---

Using table $index as unique field: *(available from ng-repeat)*

`<button ... name="showDB" ng-click="activateKey($index)">{{key}}</button>`

And

`<table ng-show="activeKey === $index" ... >`

Comment: thx a lot! is there any way to do it based on the index of the tables or something? because with the method you are suggesting, all the buttons that have the same key open when I click on one of them

Comment: I assumed that "key" was a unique table field. Check the updated answer